# How to run/view ExpressJS server for webpages other than index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, backend

So, I want to view/run/display webpages other than the index.html from my public folder which has multiple html files using ExpressJS and NodeJS. Every time I run my server, I can only view the index.html file. Is there a way I can access other html files? I am a beginner and just getting started with the backend part.
This is my app.js

```
 app=express();
const path=require('path');
const Router=express.Router();
const port=process.env.PORT||3000;
require("./db/connectdb");

const static_path=path.join(__dirname,"../../frontend/public");
app.use(express.static(static_path));

app.get('/createelection',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Create an Election here");
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('Server is running at port no. '+ port);
});
```

My Public Folder

```
Public
    -index.html
    -createelection.html
    -voterlogin.html
```

Comment: That code looks like it should serve up the other files just fine. What URLs are you asking for in the browser? What responses do you get?

Comment: I was trying to view the other html files. I was getting the "cannot get" errors.

Comment: Again: What URLs are you visiting that are giving you those errors?

Comment: localhost:3000, localhost:3000/createelection; But, Now it's working after I added the res.SendFile(path.join(.....)) thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment on the question:

> `localhost:3000/createelection`

By default the static module will:

- Give you `index.html` if you ask for a path ending in `/`
- Give you the file you ask for

You are asking for `createelection` but the file is named `createelection.html`.

With your current code you need to ask for `http://localhost:3000/createelection.html`.

Alternatively you can tell Express to try to autocomplete the file extension for you. Look at the documentation for [the static module](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static):

> **extensions**:   Sets file extension fallbacks: If a file is not found, search for files with the specified extensions and serve the first one found. Example: `['html', 'htm']`.

The setting defaults to `false`

So you would need:

```
app.use(express.static(static_path, { extensions: true }));
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understood how to use express.static properly.